# I can not evaluate a function for an array problem

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a function to evaluate and I want to graph it point by point. But the function only gives me a value and not the set of evaluated values.

```
rho = 0.999;
n = -10:1:10;
x = (rho.^(n))*(1 - rho)
y = 1 - (rho.^(n + 1))
Pb = x/y
plot(n, Pb)
```

`x` is a `1x21 double` array just like `y` but my evaluated function `Pb` is a single value, not a set of evaluated values. Therefore I do not get my graph

What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to divide each element of `x` by its corresponding `y`? Fix the line

```
Pb = x./ y;
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for